# How to patch/mock a method in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, swift4

I'm not experienced in Swift yet.

if I have a piece of code that does this:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Constants.isTermsAccepted) == false {
    openDisclaimer()
}
```

In Python I could patch the openDisclaimer() method to replace it with a MagicMock. Once I run the test and the assert would reveal if that MagicMock was called or not. I don't care what is happening inside that method, only that it was called or not.

Is something like that possible in Swift?

**UPDATE**:

Adding the method's implementation

```
func openDisclaimer() {
        let popupVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "disclaimerPopUp") as! DisclaimerViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popupVC)
        popupVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
        popupVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mock (/swizzle) arbitrary Swift functions, they are often statically bound instead of dynamically dispatched (a reason why it is supposed to be swift). You need to design your code around this, e.g. use protocols and dependency injection, instead of calling concrete functions.

OCMock has a nice [blog entry](http://ocmock.org/swift/) about issues around this.

Updating for the update:
The "method's implementation" is the stuff you want to mock/replace. Hence you need to inject that dependency to the code calling openDisclaimer. There are many ways to do this, one is to pass in a closure.

Old:

```
func showDisclaimerIfNecessary() {
  if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Constants.isTermsAccepted) {
    openDisclaimer()
  }
}
```

New testable:

```
func showDisclaimerIfNecessary(_ action: () ->() = openDisclaimer) {
  if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: Constants.isTermsAccepted) {
    action()
  }
}
```

Invoke for production:

```
showDisclaimerIfNecessary()
```

Invoke for testing:

```
var didCall = false
showDisclaimerIfNecessary() {
  didCall = true
}
XCTAssert(didCall, "....")
```

But quite often you probably want to structure your code around abstract types and inject them as a dependency (instead of doing the fine grained way using closures as shown above).

Comment: Thank you, this helps.  I can see that external dependencies such as APIs can be mocked like this. I still have trouble understanding how to do TDD with methods that are not part of a service, but rather part of my view-controller.  I have updated my question with the implementation of the given method.  Going by that advice, I shouldn't check if the method was called, but rather mock `DisclaimerViewController ` and override `didMove()` and see if `popupVC.didMove()` returns true in my test.  Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!